# Can fractional/decimal radicals/roots exist?

Tags: radicals, decimal-expansion, radical-equations

For questions like "What is the 1/2th root of x would the answer be $x^2$?

My logic is that since $$
\sqrt[\cfrac{1}{2}]{x}=x^{1/{(\cfrac{1}{2}})}
$$
Which simplifies to $x^2$.

So as a general rule it could be $$
\sqrt[\cfrac{1}{a}]{x}=x^{1/{(\cfrac{1}{a}})}
=x^a
$$

And with a different denominator $$\sqrt[\cfrac{b}{a}]{x}=x^{1/{(\cfrac{b}{a}})}
=x^{\cfrac{a}{b}}$$

This corresponds to how decimal/fractional exponents denote radicals (their inverse) while fractional radicals are easier shown with exponents.

Example : (2/3rd root of 4)

$$\sqrt[\cfrac{2}{3}]{4}=4^{1/{(\cfrac{2}{3}})}
=4^{\cfrac{3}{2}}= 8$$

Example (22/7th root of π) :

$$\sqrt[\cfrac{22}{7}]{π}=π^{1/{(\cfrac{22}{7}})}
=π^{\cfrac{7}{22}}
\approx 1.439$$

Example (1/2th root of 1/4) :

$$\sqrt[\cfrac{1}{2}]{\cfrac{1}{4}}=\cfrac{1}{4}^{1/(\cfrac{2}{1})}
=\cfrac{1}{4}^{(\cfrac{2}{1})}
=\cfrac{1}{4}^{2}
=\cfrac{1}{16}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The definition is:

$$\sqrt[a]{x} = x^{\frac{1}{a}}.$$

Hence, if $a = \frac{1}{b}$, then:

$$\sqrt[\frac{1}{b}]{x} = x^{b}.$$

As a consequence:

$$\sqrt[\frac{1}{2}]{x} = x^2.$$

---

Notice that $a = \frac{1}{b}$ implies that, if for example $b = \frac{22}{91}$, then $a = \frac{91}{22}$. If for example $b = \sqrt{3}$, then $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. And so on.

Comment: That looks like the second line of the question ("general rule")

Comment: There is nothing more to say about this